# puppet kick and environment variable

Tags: linux, ubuntu, puppet

I have the following as puppet steps:

```
file { '/etc/profile.d/spark_submit.sh' :
        content => "export SPARK_HOME=/var/lib/spark/spark\nexport PATH=\$PATH:\$SPARK_HOME/bin/\n",
    }    
    ->
file_line { 'spark_submit_bashrc':
        path => '/etc/bash.bashrc',
        line => "source /etc/profile.d/spark_submit.sh"
    }
```

The files are correctly generated. The environment variables are present in the command line both as root and non-root. However, if I do a puppet kick from an external machine, the environment variables seem to not be present. i.e. if I fun puppet agent -t from the box itself, it runs fine. If I do a puppet kick from another box, the SPARK_HOME variable isn't set. Is there a location I can register the variable so that it's available when running puppet kick?

Note: this is on ubuntu (trusty) with puppet 3.7.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will go ahead and assume that the actual issue is that with `puppet kick`, you contact a long-running agent process that listens for connection. It will only refresh its environment on restart, so you would need to trigger a restart of the `puppet agent` service upon changing the files.